# show Title Of Image on Click

Tags: jquery, slideup

I have tried the following in Wordpress to show the title on click of the parent Div

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#thumbnailwrap" ).click(function() {
       $( ".titlewrap" ).slideUp( "slow", function() {
// Animation complete.
       });
    });
});
```

Ive checked for Syntax errors. Can anyone advise where i may have gone wrong?

Comment: What errors are you getting? You may want to check your browser console if you're unsure. Also, a JSFiddle containing your problematic area would help a lot.

Comment: im only getting this one event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. .. which i dont believe is related :S

Comment: For starters, do you always want to show the same div? Is it hidden when you try to slide it?

Comment: Alright, no, that is not an error. That is a warning that comes when debugging in Google Chrome, and you should not worry about it. Please explain what the part is that isn't working with it. Doesn't it slide up?

Comment: basically its a title inside a div (thumbnail image wordpress) and i want it to show the title so i nested it inside the div, so when you hover or click or whatever the thumbnail div that the title showed and faded out

Comment: That's the goal, what is the problem?

Comment: it isnt showing on click or on hover... the div is staying hidden so i assumed i had written something wrong with the code.

Comment: Replace `$(document).ready(function() {...` with `jQuery(function($) {...`

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's `slideUp` method will slide an element's height *to zero*, so is designed to hide an element by sliding it up until it is invisible.

You could try switching `slideUp` with `slideDown`, which is designed to take an element with zero height and slide it down to its target height, hence making it visible. ([documentation for `slideDown`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#thumbnailwrap" ).click(function() {
       $( ".titlewrap" ).slideDown( "slow", function() {
           // Animation complete.
       });
    });
});
```

Or, if you want the title to switch between being hidden and visible whenever you click `#thumbnailwrap`, you could try `slideToggle` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( "#thumbnailwrap" ).click(function() {
       $( ".titlewrap" ).slideToggle( "slow", function() {
           // Animation complete.
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Jack, thankyou very much i did it with the slidetoggle, i thought the slide up meant it literally popped up :) thankyou :)

Comment: And [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/FurZ7/) a JSFiddle containing the solution you suggested.

Comment: hi Jack, quick one! its actually showing Everything with the same class! Yikes, i want it to do it for an individual parent in wordpress, is that possible? I got an example

Comment: http://www.fivetalents.co.uk/meet-the-team/ when you click info the info slides in

Comment: @KirstyHarris [Here's an updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FurZ7/1/) where the only `.titlewrap` div being slided is the child of the concurrent wrapper being clicked. By using the general `.titlewrap` selector, you select ALL elements on the page with that selector. Instead, you find the `.titlewrap` elements inside the element being clicked.